# UserControl throwing: Element is already the child of another element

Tags: uwp

I am developing an UWP app in which I required a Accordion. Since, UWP toolkit does not provides the accordion control therefore, I have create my own `Accordion` control. And it works like a charm.

The problem is, when I create multiple instances of my usercontrol then it throws an exception. I have shared a stripped down sample on the following link:

https://1drv.ms/u/s!AiCx3o82H3zNu1DrZxtQ_sTYYf-D

Comment: Yes... It's the very first thing I think everyone follows before posting any questions

Comment: The error message is quite clear so does the answer - 'Control can have only one parent'. Your question in current form seems to be a duplicate. Please try to narrow down the issue, edit question - it would be much better if you have put some code how you define controls and when the error comes.

Comment: If you have some time then please review the provided same. I tried every possible workaround but did not find any solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what the problem is. (I think it's to do with having a static backing property that defaults to an object and is then included in each control but can't prove it.)

However, there's an easy fix.
Instead of using your `MydesqAccordionUserControl.xaml` which basically wraps and then tries to re-implement an `ItemsControl` you can inherit from it.
Remove `MydesqAccordionUserControl.xaml` and `MydesqAccordionUserControl.xaml.cs` rom your project and replace them with a class containing the code below. Problem sorted.

```
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls;

namespace MydesqAccordionUserControl
{
    public class MydesqAccordionControl : ItemsControl
    {
        public void CollapseOtherItems(MydesqAccordionItem item)
        {
            if (Items != null)
            {
                foreach (var mydesqAccordionItem in Items)
                {
                    if (!mydesqAccordionItem.Equals(item))
                    {
                        (mydesqAccordionItem as MydesqAccordionItem)?.CollapseContent();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```